# Access 2007 query to count different values in the same column

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm using Access 2007.  In `column1` are the values (Week 1, Week 2, Week 3) and in `column2` are the cost centers (01, 03, 05, 12, 24, etc.).  I'm trying to create a query that will count all instances of `column1` for each cost center and display the results in 3 different columns.  For example:

```
Cost Center      Week1     Week2    Week3
01             15       25        3
03              8        10       12
05             200       11       55
```

Doesn't seem like it should be too hard but I can't get it to work. Here is the code that works only if I count a particular week

```
SELECT Mid([TransTable]![LGCY_IORG_ID],1,2) AS Expr1, 
       Count(TransTable.Week) AS CountOfWeek
FROM TransTable
WHERE (((TransTable.Week)="Week 1"))
GROUP BY Mid([TransTable]![LGCY_IORG_ID],1,2);
```

I'd like to get Week 1 in one column, Week 2 in another column, and week 3 in a 3rd column,  thanks for the help.

Comment: Provide sample source data. Perhaps a CROSSTAB query is appropriate.

Comment: Do you want data grouped by month and year as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT column2 As CostCenter, 
IIF(column1 = 'Week 1' , column2 , 0) As Week1,
IIF(column1 = 'Week 2' , column2 , 0) As Week2,
IFF(column1 = 'Week 3' , column2 , 0) As Week3 
FROM TransTable
GROUP BY column2
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the Crosstab Query Wizard.

Row headings will be the cost center column.
Column headings are the column with the Week descriptions.
Values will be Count of Week.

Comment: ..............thanks for the suggestion.  I've haven't used a Crosstab query before but I will definitely give that a try